# to move all file with certain common string except the extension of the file to another directory

Tags: command-line

Suppose there is directory with files and most of them have **"ubuntu"** string in common to the name of  file .

i used the command

```
mv ubuntu1 ubuntu2 ubuntu3 ubuntu/
```

now i want to move all these files from this directory to other directory without moving each file differently.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the command

```
mv *ubuntu* destination_directory_path/
```

where `*ubuntu*` indicates that ubuntu may appear anywhere in between the file/folder name.

**NOTE:** This will move **all** files which have `ubuntu` in their name in the current directory and the destination folders name should not have `ubuntu` in it. If it is present, first rename the destination to somthing else and then try the above command.

Comment: How would someone make this case insensitive? So it would move *ubuntu* and *Ubuntu*?

Comment: @b_dubb You can use the same command but use group matching like this `mv *[Uu]buntu* destination_directory_path/` . It's not exactly case insensitive matching since you have to define each group yourself but if you have specific letters you want to make that will work.